# Find the equations of $x-y$, $x-z$ and $z-y$ planes.

Tags: 3d

Do the $y-x$ and $x-y$ planes have the same equations? I think that the equation of the $x-y$ plane can be $x+y+z=0$ or $x+y+z=4$ or $ax+by+cz=$ any real number and $a,b,c$ are arbitrary real numbers. Am I wrong?

Comment: How exactly do the $xy$- and $yx$-planes themselves differ?

Answer (score 0):

x-y plane is the plane containing the line $x=0;z=0$ and $y=0;z=0$ The plane equation is $$z=0$$ x-y plane and y-x plane have the same equation. $z=0$

Comment: Is it possible to represent the equation of the x-y plane as a vector? would the vector that represents the x-y plane be $\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\0 \end{bmatrix}$? Would  the vector $\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\3 \end{bmatrix}$ still represent the x-y plane?

Comment: The vector would be \begin{bmatrix}x\\y\\0 \end{bmatrix}

Answer (score 0):

*Every* plane in three-dimensional Cartesian space has an equation
of the form
$$ ax + by + cz + d = 0,$$
where $a$, $b$, $c$, and $d$ are real numbers.
The choice of *which* numbers to use as the values of
$a$, $b$, $c$, and $d$ determines what plane you get.

The $x,y$ plane is the plane that contains the $x$ axis and the $y$ axis.
If you let each point $(x,y,z)$ in Cartesian space correspond
to a vector $\small\begin{bmatrix} x \\[-.7ex] y \\[-.7ex] z \end{bmatrix}$,
the $x,y$ plane consists of any linear combination of the vectors
$e_1 = \small\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\[-.7ex] 0 \\[-.7ex] 0 \end{bmatrix}$
and $e_2 = \small\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\[-.7ex] 1 \\[-.7ex] 0 \end{bmatrix}$.
In that sense the plane is described by two vectors.

The $x,y$ plane also has an equation of the form $ ax + by + cz + d = 0,$
but for this plane $a = b = d = 0$ and $c$ can be any non-zero
real number. We can set $c= 1$, for example, in which case the 
equation $ ax + by + cz + d = 0$ becomes
$$ 0\cdot x + 0 \cdot y + 1 \cdot z + 0 = 0,$$
that is,
$$  z = 0 .$$

Another fact about a plane with the equation $ ax + by + cz = d,$
in general, is that the vector 
$\small\begin{bmatrix} a \\[-.7ex] b \\[-.7ex] c \end{bmatrix}$
is perpendicular to that plane.
The plane consists of points corresponding to all vectors
$\small\begin{bmatrix} x \\[-.7ex] y \\[-.7ex] z \end{bmatrix}$
such that
$$\begin{bmatrix} a & b & c \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} x \\[-.7ex] y \\[-.7ex] z \end{bmatrix} + d = 0.$$
In the case of the $x,y$ plane, recalling that $a = b = d = 0$ 
for that plane, the vector
$\small\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\[-.7ex] 0 \\[-.7ex] 1 \end{bmatrix}$
is perpendicular to the plane.
In that sense there is a single vector defining the plane.